# How should I implement environment variable substitution in a JSON configuration file being serialized by NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: json, json.net, interpolation

I currently use `NewtonSoft.Json` to convert between JSON and a `Config` model. I would like to be able to accept environment variable macros in the JSON, like so:

```
{
   ...,
   "myStringVar": "${MY_STRING}",
   "myArrayVar": ${MY_ARRAY},
   ...
}
```

Currently I do this by interpolating the raw JSON with environment variables and then deserializing, like so:

```
var interpolatedConfigText = configText.InterpolateWithEnvironmentVariables();
var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(interpolatedConfigText, new StringEnumConverter());
```

This works well enough but the obvious downside is that when I go to save this file, I have no record of the fact that certain settings were actually obtained from environment variables, so those that were get overwritten:

```
{
   ...,
   "myStringVar": "string value",
   "myArrayVar": [ 0, 1 ],
   ...
}
```

Is there a clever way I can incorporate a custom serializer to accomplish this without having to, say, change the types of all of my members to some kind of representation that has both a possibly-null environment variable name, and its actual value? Just looking for the right direction to go in to achieve something like this.